# Scrollbars on the User Reputation Leagues

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, reputation-leagues

I recently went on to the yearly User Reputation Leagues for Puzzling, and to my surprise, some of the entries had scrollbars for seemingly no reason:

[image: Puzzling scrollbars]

I investigated further, and it appears that these scrollbars appear on every 4th entry (though this changes with zooming in or out). Furthermore, not only Puzzling is affected, nor only the yearly rankings (here is an image of Programming Puzzles and Code Golf on quarterly rankings):

[image: Code Golf scrollbars]

> What is causing this to happen? Can this be fixed?

<sup>Specs: Windows 10, Google Chrome 62.0.3202.75, full-screen, screen resolution 1920x1080, no userscripts, only AdBlock plugin (but still occurs if disabled)</sup>

Comment: No repro... first thing I'll check is userscripts/browser plugins you've installed. Try disabling all of them and see if it's working.

Comment: @ShadowWizard still occurs with AdBlock disabled, only plugin I've got

Comment: What about zoom? Make sure page is not zoomed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, the page isn't zoomed, but zooming in and out changes the items on which the scrollbars appear

Comment: Out of ideas... let's hope a developer will be able to reproduce.